# adding icon to link/button

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I currently have a link and I'm using it as a button look to it and I would like to add an icon to it.

Example: a plus sign `+` icon next to a word that will say Add User. Here is my link:

```
<a class="glossyBtn" href='<%:Url.Action("Edit", "Case", new{caseId = Model}) %>'>Cancel</a>
```

Here is my `.glossyBtn` style:

```css
.glossyBtn
{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #c1e2f4;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #eeeeee), color-stop(100%, #cccccc));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #b1daf1);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #b1daf1);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #b1daf1);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #b1daf1);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #b1daf1);
    border: 1px solid #3e95c8;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #3e95c8 !Important;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #046fad !Important;
    font: bold 12px Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 5px 12px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #eee;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

**Live demo: [Tinkerbin](http://tinkerbin.com/gD4FPqLB)**

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but the following should work with proper positioning:

```
<a class="glossyBtn" href='<%:Url.Action("Edit", "Case", new{caseId = Model}) %>'><span><img src="plus.png" alt=""></span>Cancel</a>
```

By prefixing the text with a `<span>` containing an `<img>`, you can insure the image stays inline with the text on the right.

Comment: This seems to work but for some reason all my images are not displayed properly as if they are missing or do not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`:after`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp) pseudo-selector:

```css
.glossyBtn:after {
    content: '+'; 
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

**Live demo: [Tinkerbin](http://tinkerbin.com/R0rQizyw)**

---

If you want to add the plus character *before* the text, use [`:before`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp) pseudo-selector:

```css
.glossyBtn:before {
    content: '+'; 
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

**Live demo: [Tinkerbin](http://tinkerbin.com/Jy0NqjZB)**

---

*I've added padding left/right, to make some space between the text and the plus character.*

Comment: This looks very interesting. I will give it a go and see - i need about 15 different buttons so i will see how easy i could make it to be generic